# NUC7 either no sound or no video

Tags: grub2, video, hdmi, intel, nomodeset

I have bought a NUC7PJYH with UHD605 graphics because our new 50" UHD tv was to big a mouthfull for my old Acer Revo 3610 with Nvidia ION as a Mythtv frontend.

I installed Xubuntu 18.04 and Mythtv-frontend on the NUC and connected the TV via HDMI-1.
1,st error was, when I boot the NUC the tv says no input at the HDMI port. If I pull out the HDMI and plug it in again, I get the desktop.

I startet out trying to fix the missing desktop by setting the "nomodeset" in the grub boot. It corrected the missing desktop but when nomodeset i set in GRUB I have no sound through HDMI. Pavucontrol states that there is a HDMI output but it is unplugged even though it is plugged in.

If I remove the nomodeset parameter in grub i have sound over HDMI but I need to unplug and replug the HDMI after every boot to get a desktop on the TV.

I have tried many different screen resolutions between 3680x2160 and 1024x768 but the problem persists. I have also tried to set the resolution in grub with the command video=1024x768.

Grub commands as ind /etc/default/grub and under GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=
and running update-grub afterwards.

What parameter do I need to set in grub to have both picture and sound. Any good suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is caused because the Intel firmware for the i915 GPU isn't loaded by the standard Ubuntu 18.04 kernel. The fimrware that needs to be loaded is:
glk_dmc_ver1_04.bin

The newer kernels loads the firmware without errors. 
Whith these newer kernels all the minor errors when coupling a display to the NUC7PJYH disappears.

I am presently using kernel 4.18.x and everything is fine

I am switching kernels by using UUKU ppa

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:teejee2008/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ukuu
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem with NUC7PJYH and an old LED TV. When I switch on the TV after powering up the NUC, I get the display alright.

So, instead of unplugging the HDMI, I would either change inputs - HDMI1>HDMI2>VGA etc. or restart the TV. I'm afraid I don't know a better fix.